Can´t install shazamio on MacOs?
i try to install the python shazamio package using the following command
pip install shazamio

Generally the solution works fine on my windows computer but on Mac i get this error when trying to install the package -
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
       maturin failed
        Caused by: Can't find /private/var/folders/q1/288l_zvn2sl7_lx4cv34yz3m0000gn/T/pip-install-ncjk92fq/shazamio-core_d948f73e48d346ff9dec627058e2b80c/Cargo.toml (in /private/var/folders/q1/288l_zvn2sl7_lx4cv34yz3m0000gn/T/pip-install-ncjk92fq/shazamio-core_d948f73e48d346ff9dec627058e2b80c)
      Error running maturin: Command '['maturin', 'pep517', 'write-dist-info', '--metadata-directory', '/private/var/folders/q1/288l_zvn2sl7_lx4cv34yz3m0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-lcpjwpc7', '--interpreter', '/Users/polzimac/Documents/DEV/venv/shazamio/bin/python3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      Running `maturin pep517 write-dist-info --metadata-directory /private/var/folders/q1/288l_zvn2sl7_lx4cv34yz3m0000gn/T/pip-modern-metadata-lcpjwpc7 --interpreter /Users/polzimac/Documents/DEV/venv/shazamio/bin/python3`
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I have allready installed Rust using the following statemnt
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh


You have installed rustup, which is a tool used to manage Rust toolchains. But have you installed any toolchain with it? Can you run rustc --version?

I think i found a solution here:
These are the steps to do:
git clone https://github.com/shazamio/shazamio-core.git
cd shazamio-core
git switch --detach 1.0.7 (OR git switch --detach 1.0.7)
python -m pip install .
pip install shazamio

Then the installation was possible on Mac
